# Is there an equivalent of cgi.parse() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am trying to run the following program:

```
#!/Python33/python
# Demonstrates get method with an XHTML form.

import urllib.parse
import cgi
import cgitb
import html
cgitb.enable()

def printHeader( title ):
    print("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8")
    print()
    print("<html>")
    print("<head><title>Test</title></head>")
    print("<body>")
    print(title)
    print("</body>")
printHeader( "Using 'get' with forms" )
print ('''<p>Enter one of your favorite words here:<br /></p>
    <form method = "get" action = "method.py">
        <p><input type = "text" name = "word"/>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit word"/>
        </p>
   </form>''')
pairs = cgi.parse();
if pairs.has_key("word"):
    print ('''<p>Your word is:
        <span style = "font-weight: bold">%s</span></p>''') \
    % html.escape( pairs[ "word" ][ 0 ] )
print ("</body></html>")
print()
```

when I run it, I get the following error :

```
    22         </p>
    23    </form>''')
=>  24 pairs = cgi.parse();
    25 if pairs.has_key("word"):
    26     print ('''<p>Your word is:
pairs undefined, cgi = <module 'cgi' from 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\cgi.py'>, cgi.parse undefined
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse' 
     args = ("'module' object has no attribute 'parse'",) 
     with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of AttributeError object>
```

I am using Python 3.3, I can't find if there is an alternate to `cgi.parse()` that I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cgi.parse exists in python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/cgi.html), however you have a python file named cgi.py and it is finding that.

Here is where the badly named cgi.py file lives:

```
<module 'cgi' from 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software 
Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\cgi.py'>
```

[python 3.3 does not have "has_key" though](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)...

So you'll get an error on this line:

```
if pairs.has_key("word"):
```

Changing that to:

```
if "word" in pairs:
```

Makes the code work properly for me.

Output:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
Using 'get' with forms
</body>
<p>Enter one of your favorite words here:<br /></p>
    <form method = "get" action = "method.py">
        <p><input type = "text" name = "word"/>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit word"/>
        </p>
   </form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information, i was in fact referring another file named cgi.

Answer (score 0):

[`cgi.parse()` exists in Python 3.3.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse) You've called some other file "cgi.py", and Python is finding this instead. Rename that file and any related .py[co] files.